# How to Set Attachment Type in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I want to a add attachment type filed in work item Attachment , the main aim is control the some document before changing status in work item.
for example when i want to transit user story from new to approved it should be include Analysis document. So I want add a field to in attachment to set type of documents (my own types, ex. Analyse Document,User request,Budget Document and etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, This is not possible.

Plus, very far from how user stories are intended.

Comment: do you have any suggestion to categories document?

Comment: You can add a comment. That's about it.